# Check if String Contains Substring

Tags: python, string, boolean, contains

Please help me to solve this!

Question:
Define a function named contains_all_the_vowels(x) which returns whether x contains all the vowels (a, e, i, o, u) or not

Here's my code:

```
def contains_all_the_vowels(x):
vo= 'aeiou'
if vo in x:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

And it shows:

```
AssertionError: None is not true
```

Comment: Could you please accept the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but simple.

```py
def contains_all_the_vowels(x):
    if "a" in x and "e" in x and "i" in x and "o" in x and "u" in x:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searcing for the whole word `aeiou` instead of each character.
Use this instead :

```py
def contains_all_the_vowels(x):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    for v in vowels:
        if v not in x:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: You can also do `vowels = 'aeiou'`

Comment: Thanks! One more question, what should I do if I want to check whether if contains one of the vowels or not?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @altermetax. I went with the list to explicitly show that one is iterating through individual characters.

Comment: @夏丸子 While iterating, if you encounter even one vowel, return `True` instead

Comment: If you want "any", "all", or "none" you need to return more than True or False, so I think you'd be better served to edit your question showing how you want to handle three return cases instead of two.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. It returns False on the first vowel found. I think you meant `if v not in x:` shown in my answer. As a side note, the comprehension method of my answer should both be faster and allow easy 'any', 'all', and 'none' methods.

Comment: Thanks to all of you !

Answer (score 0):

Membership checks see if the argument on the left is in the array on the right. So `"a" in "abc"` checks if the character "a" is in "abc". while `"abc" in "string"` checks if the substring "abc" appears in "string"

To solve your problem, the verbose method would be

```
def contains_all_the_vowels(x):
  vo = 'aeiou'
  for c in vo:
    if c not in x:
      return False
  return True
```

using a list comprehension it may be written

```
def contains_all_the_vowels(x):
    return all([c in x for c in 'aeiou'])
```

The handy thing about using the list comprehension form is that it is easy to handle the "any vowels" or "all vowels" or "no vowels" cases like this:

```
def contains_all_the_vowels(x):
    occurs = [c in x for c in 'aeiou']
    if all(occurs):
        return "All vowels found"
    if any(occurs):
        return "At least one vowel found"
    return "No vowels found"
```